# How to set a class or super class of oneself to an instance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, this

Title may sounds a little bit confusing, what I mean is that I have a class A that extends class B therefore have all the properties from B, and I want to set class B to an instance (with all the variables in B changed), so in this way B get's updated from somewhere else A will have corresponding effect whlie you can operate A and make their individual interaction. Code is as following.

```
class A : public B
{
public:
    A()  {}
    ~A() {}

    void setA(B b)
    {
               // NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE
    }

};
```

In java there is `this` and `.super()` and it doesn't seem to be the same in C++, `this` is a `const` and cannot be changed and I'm not sure how the `.super()` thing works.

BTW is that possible to see the class A itself to another instance of A?

Comment: I had the same problem a while ago, and one way I find to do it was by    declaring the parent method as virtual and then scope it in the subclass.

Comment: this is a const pointer.  it is not a pointer to a const object.  what you can do in setA is this \*((B\*)this) = b;  although that is not a good way to do it.  what you should do is have a function in B called void Set(const B& b); that does the copying.  This would automatically be "inherited" by A.  The advantage here is that B knows all of its members (including private).  A doesn't know all of B's members.

Comment: "In java there is ... and it doesn't seem to be the same in C++" Of course there is. If you specify clearly what you mean in Java, we can demonstrate the equivalent in C++.

Answer (score 0):

## Preface:

In Java if you write,

```
A a1 = new A();
A a2 = a1;
```

then `a1` and `a2` are referring to same object.
But in C++, the story is little different. You may not need `new A()` always to create an object.

Suppose you create an *automatic* object as below:

```
A a1; // a1 is created on stack
A a2 = a1; // a2 is created on stack and copied from a1
```

Note that `a1` and `a2` are different objects with same values. They are not referring to same entity. If you want `a2` to be reference of `a1` then write it as below:

```
A &a2 = a1;
```

If you want to simulate original Java behavior, then pointers are useful:

```
A *a1 = new A();
A *a2 = a1;
```

## Answer:

By now, you will know the difference between C++ object and reference from above.

Having said that, C++ has better way to set an object rather than using `setA()`. You can simply overload the `operator =`

```
class A : public B
{
  int member; // some member variable

public:
  A& operator = (const A &a) // don't need to use `B&`
  {
    *(static_cast<B*>(this)) = a; // this calls `B::operator =`
    this->member = a.member;  // copy other members likewise
    return *this;
  }
};
```

Usage:

```
A a1, a2;
a1 = a2; // calls B::operator = and A::operator =
```

Also note that, you may not always need `operator =` to be defined inside the class. There are some *special* cases when you actually need it. By default compiler generates a copy constructor and assignment operator and performs the copying for you.

Comment: "the story is little different" The "story" is not different. The *syntax* is different between languages. "If you want to simulate original Java behavior" It's not "simulate"; it's simply the syntax in C++ that is equivalent to that Java code.

Comment: I would skip the cast and just do `B::operator=(a);`.

Comment: @newacct, no the stories are really different. In Java you can reassign the reference (like C++ pointer), but in C++ you cannot. Why I wrote "simulate" is because, both pointers and Java's reference are not exactly same, but somewhat same.

Comment: @iammilind: Java's "reference" is a pointer to an object. You can reassign a pointer in C++. It is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I figure that you only want to call `setA(B b)` only once, so that when `b` changes, `A` sees the latest value? If so, you are attempting to replace the sub-object, which is not possible.

For the use case you are attempting to achieve, it would be apt if `B*` were a member variable. Is there any reason why `B` has to be a base class of `A`?. It would be better if you give a concrete example with real names or explain in more detail.